How to change the font of added text in pyautocad or win32com?
This code adds MTEXT text elements to an autocad drawing. I need the font of this text to be Arial:
for coordinates in gold_marker_coords:
    x, y, z, text_value = coordinates
    m_text = ms.AddMText(APoint(x + 0.8, y - 1, z), 1, str(text_value))
    m_text.Height = 1.5
    m_text.Layer = 'Скважины'

In the Autocad object model I found only the StyleName text property. It only contains the names of the 'STANDARD' and 'Annotative' styles. I can't find anything about fonts. I know how to create a font manually in the document itself. But I need a way for pyautoca or win32com.

You'll need to create/modify a Textstyle which references the target font - the relevant property of the Textstyle is the fontfile property

@LeeMac, How do I do this in my code? I don't quite understand how to build a sequence of commands

As Lee mentioned, set the fontFile property
def PyRxCmd_doit():
try:
    axApp = Ax.getApp()
    axDoc = axApp.ActiveDocument
    ts = axApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveTextStyle
    ts.fontFile = "c:\\windows\\fonts\\Symbol.ttf"
    axDoc.ModelSpace.AddMText([0,0,0],1,"Hello world")
except Exception as err:
    traceback.print_exception(err)

